# Excel If Function with too many arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, code

IT tells me that there are too many arguments, but I don't know how to make it less arguments for it to work
cant seem to make this one work,

```
=IF(ToFind<MyNumber,"Too low",  IF(ToFind>MyNumber,"Too high","Got it!"), If(ISBLANK(ToFind),""))
```

toFind and MyNumber are named cells

Comment: Hi @Jack,, better share some sample data with us, help us to fix it properly. Since U are handling Named Range ( more than one cell/Range of cells ),, may be this need as array (CSE) formula,,!

Answer (score 1):

put the ISBLANK first:

```
=If(ISBLANK(ToFind),"",IF(ToFind<MyNumber,"Too low",  IF(ToFind>MyNumber,"Too high","Got it!")))
```

Comment: Yes, you need to put `ISBLANK` as first parameter. As I can see from the logic there is not point of comparing down the line if `ToFind` is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `IF` is: `=IF([logical test],[result if test = true],[result if test = false])`.

You have `=IF([ToFindMyNumber],[result1],[result2]),[bunch of other stuff that won't evaluate])`

I don't know what 'ToFindMyNumber' means. If it's a logical test - that is, a relationship that will return either a TRUE or FALSE value, then everything up to your first `)` is syntactically valid, and you'll get back either "Too high" or "Got it!" depending on its result.

It seems like you may be trying to nest ifs? You didn't actually say what you're trying to do. It may help to edit that into your question. Short of that, just make sure you're sticking to the overall syntax, and mind your brackets.

Example: Starting with the basic syntax `=IF([logical test],[result if true],[result if false])` we can expand out - what if the first test is false and you want to try something else?

`=IF([logical test],[result if true],[result if false])`

`=IF([logical test],[result if true],[IF([logical test],[result if true],[result if false])])`

See how another entire `IF` evaluation fits inside the `[result if false]' argument from the first one? That's how you do that.